# PHP strings replace in a file

Tags: php

I have a php file like this.

```
define('TEXT_ONE',  'testvalue1');

define('TEXT_TWO',  'testvalue12');

define('TEXT_THREE', 'testvalue13');

define('TEXT_FOUR',  'testvalue14');

define('TEXT_FIVE',  'testvalue15');

define('TEXT_SIX', 'testvalue16');

define('TEXT_SEVEN',   'testvalue17');

define('TEXT_EIGHT',       'testvalue18');


define('TEXT_NINE', 'testvalue19');

define('TEXT_TEN', 'testvalue10);

define('TEXT_ELEVEN', 'testvalue11');
```

I want to change some of the defined value through php code.

for ex:- I Want to change above file to

```
define('TEXT_ONE',  'newtext1');

define('TEXT_TWO',  'newtext12');

define('TEXT_THREE',  'newtext13');

define('TEXT_FOUR',     'newtext14');

define('TEXT_FIVE',        'newtext15');

define('TEXT_SIX', 'newtext16');

define('TEXT_SEVEN',   'newtext17');

define('TEXT_EIGHT',       'newtext18');

define('TEXT_NINE', 'testvalue19');

define('TEXT_TEN', 'newtext10);

define('TEXT_ELEVEN', 'testvalue11');
```

Can any one help me?

Thanks

Comment: *Can any one help me?* With what?

Comment: Syntax error in `define('TEXT_TEN', 'testvalue10);` and `define('TEXT_TEN', 'newtext10);` for one thing.

Comment: Maybe str_replace() will be helpful, although i'm not sure what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

`define` — Defines a named constant.

As the name suggests, that value cannot change during the execution of the script

Comment: Maybe you also want to take a look at the dupe.